# How can we get the text from scrolledtext and create a pdf

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry, tkinter-button, tkinter-text

I wrote this code but after clicking the generate pdf button it gives blank page pdf as an output with no text at all.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.filedialog import asksaveasfile, asksaveasfilename
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.styles import ParagraphStyle
from reportlab.platypus import Paragraph
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import  A4
from tkinter import scrolledtext

my_w = tk.Tk()
my_w.geometry("400x300")
my_w.title("PDF GENERATOR")
b1=tk.Button(text='Generate PDF',command=lambda:gen_pdf())
b1.grid(row=2,column=0,padx=20,pady=10)
infodescr = tk.scrolledtext.ScrolledText(my_w, width=70, height=12,wrap=WORD,font = ('calibre',12))
infodescr.grid(row=1, column=0,   sticky=E+W+N+S,padx=5,pady=5)
infodescr.insert(INSERT,"Hello this is the sample pdf \n you are welcome!")

my_Style = ParagraphStyle('My Para style',fontName="Times-Roman",fontSize=16,
     alignment=0, borderWidth=2,borderColor='#FFFF00',backColor = '#F1F1F1',
                          borderPadding = (20, 20, 20),leading = 20)
width, height = A4
def gen_pdf():
    my_path = asksaveasfilename(filetypes=[('PDF files', '*.pdf')], defaultextension=".pdf")
    if my_path:
        text = infodescr.get("1.0", END)
        text = text.replace('\n', '<BR/>')
        p1 = Paragraph(text, my_Style)
        c = canvas.Canvas(my_path, pagesize=A4)
        p1.wrapOn(c, 300, 50)
        p1.drawOn(c, width - 800, height - 1000)
        c.save()
my_w.mainloop()
```

I have tried the same with entry widget and it works fine with the entered value but for the inserted value it returns blank file with no text.

Comment: `p1.drawOn(c, width - 800, height - 1000)` draws at area out of the paper.

Comment: now it shows error in line `p1.wrapOn(c, 300, 50)`